# regexp_match function of PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I wanted to use the `regexp_match` function of `PostgreSQL` for comparing the keywords column of one table with the description column in the other. The result, in this case, will be null or not null and by using the CASE statement it will return either True or False.
The matching will be in such a way that if there is an extra character before or after the expression the pattern should not match and give a False value, but in my case, it returns true and I want it False. The expression is shown in the screenshot.[scheenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDEsb.png). The code where I want to implement this matching function is here.[Original Case to change the pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBVUx.png)

In order to solve this I have used different wild cards in the pattern that restrict the matching if there is an extra character before or after the expression. I used work boundary, initial word check wild cards, and many more but it didn't help in my case. The changes I have made were as shown in the screenshot.[changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRmEt.png)

Comment: I removed the irrelevant DBMS tags from your question since you're not using Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: Blind people cannot read screenshots.

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). I can't see images on the bus - they're blocked by the bus company's ISP!

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns True because you simply the regex engine to find the character string  `descr`, which it does find within `;descr;`. The answer given is correct, it is the expression that is wrong.  Rather than matching you can use regular_replace() to capture substrings before and after the target string. Then test the remaining string for `''` (0-length string) or if you must have Null the use the nullif() function. Neither requires a `case` as comparison operators return either True, False (or null); ([see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/S8zwbLh-))

```
with test_rows(aval) as 
     (values  (';descr;'), ('descr'), ('descr;'), (';descr'),('row3')) 
select aval, nval = '' 
  from ( select aval,  regexp_replace(aval,'^(.*)descr(.*)', '\1\2') nval 
           from test_rows
       ) sq;
      
ALTERNATIVE: 

with test_rows(aval) as 
     (values  (';descr;'), ('descr'), ('descr;'), (';descr'),('row3')) 
select aval, nval is null 
  from ( select aval, nullif( regexp_replace(aval,'^(.*)descr(.*)', '\1\2'), '') nval 
           from test_rows
       ) sq;
```